# Git-ftp init prefixes directories with #

Tags: git, deployment, ftp, git-ftp

Can somebody tell me please, why my **git-ftp init** renames the root directories (also the root files) on ftp server with **#** ? Like #temp, #app ... Also if I rename it after init manually, next **git ftp push** creates also prefixed directories and store uploaded files into this wrong named directories. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

may be you problem in old mingv bug (https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/269)
*update:* Try to **update** your git client)

Comment: The solution in my case was reinstall Git. I tried to update some other libraries but only reinstall Git solved the problem.

Comment: @Čamo you're right. I made misspelling in my upper answer (fixed)  -- you need to update your git client (you've already done)